# Which method stops reducers from starting the actual reduce phase in hadoop yarn?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am new to hadoop yarn and want reducers to start the actual reducing process before the completion of all the maps. I tried to find out the class where the reducers are invoked but could not find out. Can any one help me in this regard?

Comment: the title and the question mismatch (start or stop reducers?). is there a typo? Anyway, I tried to include both in my answer.

Comment: [`JobImpl.java`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/app/job/impl/JobImpl.java)

Answer (score 1):

The reducers can only start *collecting* the output of mappers, before all the mappers are completed. This is called the `shuffle` phase.

However, they cannot start the `sorting` and `reduce` phases, since they need to have **ALL** the map output records, before starting to work on them. The reason is simple:

Imagine the wordcount example and that you want to count the frequency of a word. In the reduce phase, if you emit a *value* (the frequency) of a key (the *word*), before getting the output of all the mappers (i.e., some counts are missing for this word), then, you may give the wrong frequency of a word.

You can change the time when the reducers start *collecting* (not reducing) the mappers' outputs, by setting the `mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps` property to 1, meaning that the reducers will only start when ALL the mappers are complete: `conf.set(mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps, "1.00");`. In the old API this property used to be (based on [this link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html)):

> mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps

Comment: thanks. from the research paper titiled "Breaking the mapreduce stage barrier" by Verma et al. the actual reducing can be started for certain applications before the completion of all the maps. So I am looking for the code where the reducers are invoked in yarn. can you help me?

Comment: @MSumathi then, I believe that you have to ask the authors for their implementation, as this is not the one provided by Apache (as far as I know).